# Not sorting nested hash in hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, hash

I have the following Hash that I'm trying to sort in Ruby on Rails with no luck:

```
{
  "10.0"=>{0=>"Safari", 1=>"10.0", 2=>976, 3=>827, 4=>4997, 5=>311, 6=>731, 7=>173291.0, 8=>0, 9=>48, 10=>6020.0, 11=>116}, 
  "9.0"=>{0=>"Safari", 1=>"9.0", 2=>837, 3=>689, 4=>4574, 5=>233, 6=>610, 7=>192260.0, 8=>0, 9=>49, 10=>6027.0, 11=>113}, "537.0"=>{0=>"Desktop Safari version split", 1=>"537.0", 2=>"56", 3=>"56", 4=>"99", 5=>"37", 6=>"55", 7=>"898.0", 8=>"0", 9=>"0", 10=>"0.0", 11=>"0"}, 
  "8.0"=>{0=>"Safari", 1=>"8.0", 2=>92, 3=>83, 4=>538, 5=>26, 6=>74, 7=>20681.0, 8=>0, 9=>4, 10=>317.0, 11=>8}, "6.0"=>{0=>"Desktop Safari version split", 1=>"6.0", 2=>62, 3=>51, 4=>428, 5=>20, 6=>44, 7=>11954.0, 8=>0, 9=>1, 10=>116.0, 11=>2}, 
  "5.0"=>{0=>"Safari", 1=>"5.0", 2=>48, 3=>41, 4=>259, 5=>16, 6=>35, 7=>9526.0, 8=>0, 9=>1, 10=>120.0, 11=>2}, 
  "534.0"=>{0=>"Safari", 1=>"534.0", 2=>7, 3=>7, 4=>8, 5=>6, 6=>7, 7=>45.0, 8=>0, 9=>0, 10=>0.0, 11=>0}, 
  "538.0"=>{0=>"Safari", 1=>"538.0", 2=>"6", 3=>"6", 4=>"6", 5=>"6", 6=>"6", 7=>"0.0", 8=>"0", 9=>"0", 10=>"0.0", 11=>"0"}, "7.0"=>{0=>"Safari", 1=>"7.0", 2=>20, 3=>15, 4=>99, 5=>4, 6=>13, 7=>4093.0, 8=>0, 9=>0, 10=>0.0, 11=>3}, 
  "4.0"=>{0=>"Safari", 1=>"4.0", 2=>"1", 3=>"1", 4=>"1", 5=>"1", 6=>"1", 7=>"0.0", 8=>"0", 9=>"0", 10=>"0.0", 11=>"0"}, "601.0"=>{0=>"Safari", 1=>"601.0", 2=>"1", 3=>"1", 4=>"1", 5=>"1", 6=>"1", 7=>"0.0", 8=>"0", 9=>"0", 10=>"0.0", 11=>"0"}
}
```

And I want those nested hashes to be sorted on the value from key 2.

I try the following code:

```
hash.sort_by{|k,v|v[2].to_i}
```

and

```
hash.sort{|a, b| a[2].to_i<=>b[2].to_i;}
```

But both of these don't sort anything at all. I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version works fine :

```
hash.sort_by{|k,v| v[2].to_f}
```

Did you use the sorted array, or forgot to save it in another variable?

If you want to replace hash with a sorted version of itself:

```
hash=hash.sort_by{|k,v|v[2].to_i}.to_h
```

Your second version :

```
 hash.sort{|a, b| a[2].to_i<=>b[2].to_i}
```

doesn't work because a and b are nested hashes, and a[2] is nil (There is no nested_hash with a key==2). You need :

```
hash.sort{|(k1,v1), (k2,v2)| v1[2].to_i<=>v2[2].to_i}
```

Comment: hash=hash.sort_by{|k,v|v[2].to_i}.to_h this is the one that worked for me, thank you!